# MSQL Error 1193--updating on the same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger to update a column in the same table after another update. I am given a SQL Error (1193): Unknown system variable

I thought this is fairly straightforward, but it doesn't seem to like it very much. Please help!

```
CREATE TRIGGER `redeem_gc` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `giftcards` 
FOR EACH ROW 
   IF NEW.value = 0 THEN
      SET `status`= '2'
   END IF
```

what the code should do is if the value reaches 0, then update the status to 'x'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `redeem_gc` BEFORE UPDATE ON `giftcards` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF NEW.value = 0 THEN
      SET NEW.`status`= '2';
   END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```